# WatchKit issue : SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode-6.2

The project compile fine but when I try to use Apple Watch simulator, I get this error from xCode :
    SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage

I tried to : clean project (cmd+maj+k & cmd+maj+opt+k), clean DerivedData folder, uninstall the app, change simulator type....

I checked bundles ID in iPhone app, Watchkit Extension and Watchkit App and everythings seems correct.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Watchkit simulator issue: SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286571/apple-watchkit-simulator-issue-sperrorinvalidbundlenogizmobinarymessage)

Comment: I try every solution listed in this post, but nothing works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the same Version ( CFBundleVersion ) of containing app and WatchKit app. 
This was the issue which was causing this problem in Xcode 6.2 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue. I have solved it by doing the following things.

1. Targets of **Your App, WatchKit Extension, WatchKit App** all three should have the same Build and Version number.

[image]

2. Check WatchKit Extension's info.plist and WatchKit App's info.plist. In WatchKit Extension's info.plist file check for, NSExtension > NSExtensionAttributes > WKAppBundleIdentifier. WKAppBundleIdentifier need to be the same as WatchKit App's Bundle Identifier.
3. Clean the WatchKit App project and run again.

   Worked!!

Comment: nothing is working for me. Not your solution or the others written here. I've the xCode beta 6.3 do you think it is creating this problem?
I've checked thrice and everything is fine.

Comment: Mine is XCode 6.3 as well. Delete the WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension files as well the respective targets. Add it newly again and check.