# iOS WatchKit - Error launching watch app "SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage"

Tags: ios, watchkit, bundle-identifier, ios-app-group

I am trying to build a watchKit app that will allow Two-Way communications between the iPhone App and Watch App. 
I have setup App Groups and all the proper App Certificates, Provisioning Profiles and Entitlements are set and match up. But I keep getting this error when I try to run the Watch App (no error when running just the iPhone App).

Error:

> Error Launching 'MyWatchApp WatchKit Extension'
>   SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage

I think it has something to do with the Bundle Identifiers, but as far as I can tell everything looks correct. Any suggestions?

Here are my bundle identifiers:

```
App Group Key: group.com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp

iPhone App Bundle Identifier: com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp

Watch App Bundle Identifier: com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp.watchkit
Watch App WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier: com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp

Watch Extension App Bundle Identifier: com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp.watchkit.extension
Watch Extension WKAppBundleIdentifier: com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp.watchkit
```

*Note - Changing **Watch Extension App Bundle** to "com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp.watchkit" allows me to run the app, but then I never get proper results when trying to communicate Phone -> Watch. This is specified as a bundle identifier problem in [Why won't app groups work inside my WatchKit extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885597/why-wont-app-groups-work-inside-my-watchkit-extension)*

**I have already tried the following with no success:**

- Clean / Clean Build Folder
- Deleted Derived Data
- Restarted Xcode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Watchkit simulator issue: SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286571/apple-watchkit-simulator-issue-sperrorinvalidbundlenogizmobinarymessage)

Comment: Yes it's duplicate =(

Comment: the answers in the duplicate did not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I was pretty close.
It seems that the WatchKit Extension Bundle Identifier **cannot contain** the WatchKit App Bundle Identifier.

So my problem was that

```
com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp.watchkit.extension
```

**was too similar to**

```
com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp.watchkit
```

Changed my extension identifier to the below and voilà, I can now send two-way messages using MMWormhole library:

```
com.nitwitstudios.myWatchApp.extension
```

Comment: Thought this might seem irrelevant, it's " Voilà " and not "Wa-La".

Answer (score 3):

I was using the simulator with iOS8.2; switching to iOS8.3 worked.