# Changing Watchkit extension bundle id after renaming project

Tags: ios, swift, rename, watchkit, apple-watch

After renaming my project from "apple watch company tutorial" to "Project x", i had some troubles, i solved some by checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30210346/1880500), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290992/1880500)

iPhone Application Info.plist:

```
Bundle identifier: com.company.projectx
```

Watchkit Extension Info.plist:

```
Bundle identifier: com.company.projectx.watchkitextension

WKAppBundleIdentifier: com.company.projectx.watchkitapp

RemoteInterfacePrincipalClass: com.company.projectx.watchkitextension.InterfaceController
```

WatchKit App Info.plist

```
Bundle identifier: com.company.projectx.watchkitapp

WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier: com.company.projectx
```

my starter interface is named as InterfaceController

but now i am having trouble

```
 2015-08-05 08:38:21.758 projectx WatchKit Extension[24714:1080879] WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class '_TtC46Apple_Watch_Company_Tutorial_WatchKit_Extension19InterfaceController' to instantiate
```

I think my problem still related to renaming project and manually changing bundles , but i do not know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: It seems like it's trying to locate the interface in the old named bundle, notice this part `class '_TtC46Apple_Watch_Company_Tutorial_WatchKit_Extension19InterfaceController'` still has Watch_Company_Tutorial in it. Cleaning the project might help.

Comment: I followed this and it worked for me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121727/watchkit-error-unable-to-find-interface-controller-class-to-instantiate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like changing module of class in interface was a necessity. It was named as previous module, after the change of new module which is already suggested by xcode when i click the name, it is working.

Comment: this solved my problem. For clarity - go to interface.storyboard. Go to the scripts property and re-select dropdown.